# How do I use --logLevel in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase, informix

It doesn't seem to matter what I set it to, I don't get anything that looks like additional information:

liquibase --url="jdbc:informix-sqli:INFORMIXSERVER=informix01_tcp;SQLH_TYPE=FILE;SQLH_FILE=/opt/informix/informix/etc/sqlhosts;DATABASE=wallet" --logLevel=**debug** --logFile=./lb.log --classpath=/opt/informix/informix/jdbc/lib/ifxjdbc.jar --changeLogFile ./test1ChangeLog.xml --includeTablespace=true generateChangeLog

> Starting Liquibase at Thu, 07 Mar 2019 12:30:34 GMT (version 3.6.3
>   built at 2019-01-29 11:34:48)
>
> Unexpected error running Liquibase:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: The
>   cursor has been previously released and is unavailable.
>   liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException:
>   liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: The
>   cursor has been previously released and is unavailable.   at
>   liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:279)
>     at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1058)
>     at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:199)    at
>   liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:137) Caused by:
>   liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: The
>   cursor has been previously released and is unavailable.   at
>   liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:24)    at
>   liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:277)
>     ... 3 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: The
>   cursor has been previously released and is unavailable.   at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.java:223)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:66)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:69)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:69)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:286)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.replaceObject(DatabaseSnapshot.java:407)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.includeNestedObjects(DatabaseSnapshot.java:334)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:309)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.replaceObject(DatabaseSnapshot.java:407)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.replaceObject(DatabaseSnapshot.java:429)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.includeNestedObjects(DatabaseSnapshot.java:334)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:309)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init(DatabaseSnapshot.java:102)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.(DatabaseSnapshot.java:59)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:38)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:217)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:190)
>     at
>   liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createReferenceSnapshot(DiffCommand.java:221)
>     at
>   liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createDiffResult(DiffCommand.java:143)
>     at
>   liquibase.command.core.GenerateChangeLogCommand.run(GenerateChangeLogCommand.java:46)
>     at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:19)
>     ... 4 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: The
>   cursor has been previously released and is unavailable.   at
>   liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache.get(ResultSetCache.java:101)    at
>   liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData.getForeignKeys(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:74)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.java:127)
>     ... 27 common frames omitted Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The
>   cursor has been previously released and is unavailable.   at
>   com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildException(IfxErrMsg.java:474)    at
>   com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:443)   at
>   com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:394)   at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.addException(IfxSqli.java:3191)     at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3472)     at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2379)  at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2304)   at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeFetch(IfxSqli.java:2038)     at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.getaRow(IfxSqli.java:4082)  at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.next(IfxResultSet.java:494)    at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxDatabaseMetaData.getImportedKeys(IfxDatabaseMetaData.java:5389)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData$1.fastFetch(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:126)
>     at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache.get(ResultSetCache.java:70)    ...
>   29 common frames omitted Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: null   at
>   com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildException(IfxErrMsg.java:474)    at
>   com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:443)   at
>   com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:394)   at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3477)     ... 37
>   common frames omitted
>
> For more information, please use the --logLevel flag

liquibase --url="jdbc:informix-sqli:INFORMIXSERVER=informix01_tcp;SQLH_TYPE=FILE;SQLH_FILE=/opt/informix/informix/etc/sqlhosts;DATABASE=wallet" --logLevel=**severe** --logFile=./lb.log --classpath=/opt/informix/informix/jdbc/lib/ifxjdbc.jar --changeLogFile ./test1ChangeLog.xml --includeTablespace=true generateChangeLog

> Starting Liquibase at Thu, 07 Mar 2019 12:33:46 GMT (version 3.6.3
>   built at 2019-01-29 11:34:48) Unexpected error running Liquibase:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: The
>   cursor has been previously released and is unavailable.
>   liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException:
>   liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: The
>   cursor has been previously released and is unavailable.   at
>   liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:279)
>     at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1058)
>     at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:199)    at
>   liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:137) Caused by:
>   liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: The
>   cursor has been previously released and is unavailable.   at
>   liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:24)    at
>   liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:277)
>     ... 3 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: The
>   cursor has been previously released and is unavailable.   at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.java:223)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:66)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:69)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:69)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:286)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.replaceObject(DatabaseSnapshot.java:407)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.includeNestedObjects(DatabaseSnapshot.java:334)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:309)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.replaceObject(DatabaseSnapshot.java:407)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.replaceObject(DatabaseSnapshot.java:429)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.includeNestedObjects(DatabaseSnapshot.java:334)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:309)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init(DatabaseSnapshot.java:102)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.(DatabaseSnapshot.java:59)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:38)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:217)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:190)
>     at
>   liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createReferenceSnapshot(DiffCommand.java:221)
>     at
>   liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createDiffResult(DiffCommand.java:143)
>     at
>   liquibase.command.core.GenerateChangeLogCommand.run(GenerateChangeLogCommand.java:46)
>     at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:19)
>     ... 4 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: The
>   cursor has been previously released and is unavailable.   at
>   liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache.get(ResultSetCache.java:101)    at
>   liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData.getForeignKeys(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:74)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.java:127)
>     ... 27 common frames omitted Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The
>   cursor has been previously released and is unavailable.   at
>   com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildException(IfxErrMsg.java:474)    at
>   com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:443)   at
>   com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:394)   at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.addException(IfxSqli.java:3191)     at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3472)     at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2379)  at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2304)   at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeFetch(IfxSqli.java:2038)     at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.getaRow(IfxSqli.java:4082)  at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.next(IfxResultSet.java:494)    at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxDatabaseMetaData.getImportedKeys(IfxDatabaseMetaData.java:5389)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData$1.fastFetch(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:126)
>     at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache.get(ResultSetCache.java:70)    ...
>   29 common frames omitted Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: null   at
>   com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildException(IfxErrMsg.java:474)    at
>   com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:443)   at
>   com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:394)   at
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3477)     ... 37
>   common frames omitted
>
> For more information, please use the --logLevel flag

**After both of these have run:**

ls -l ./lb.log

ls: ./lb.log: No such file or directory